# SVG / SVGPan: center graphic upon loading

Tags: javascript, svg

I had been using nested `<svg/>` and `<g/>` elements to center an SVG graphic within my browser frame.  The outer svg element had width and height of 100%, the inner had x and y set to 50%.  An inner g element had negative offset of half image size.  This was working fine but I now want to add pan and zoom functionality.

The nested SVG approach seems to be incompatible with [SVGPan](http://www.cyberz.org/blog/2009/12/08/svgpan-a-javascript-svg-panzoomdrag-library/) which gets confused.

SVGPan will only work if I start with the graphic at top-left.  I think I'll have to write a script that runs when SCG is loading/loaded to add a transform to center the top-level g in a way that is compatible with SVGPan.

How can I initialize my `<g />` with a matrix transformation that translates it thusly?

```
((viewport.width - g.width)/2, (viewport.width - g.width)/2)
```

The size of the viewport is not known when the SVG is created but I can drop some script in there to create the transform or translation.  Where should the script live and what should it do?  It needs to be compatible with SVGPan.

Comment: Instead of describing the complex hack that you have in place and ask how to get from there to a new set of functionality, perhaps you might describe what your end goal is.

Comment: End goal is SVG graphic initially centered in window.  Graphic can then be panned by dragging it or zoomed using mouse wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talos solved this issue for me, see https://github.com/talos/jquery-svgpan/issues/3

Instead of

```
<svg><svg><g></g></svg></svg>
```

I'm now using

```
<svg><g><svg></svg></g></svg>
```

and that allows a centered graphic to work with [jquery-]svgpan.

Answer (score 1):

**To fill an SVG element in any HTML element:**

1. Put `position:relative` (or `position:absolute` or `position:fixed`, if appropriate) on the wrapping HTML element.
2. Put `position:absolute` on the SVG element (and `top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%` if necessary).

With this your SVG element will always fill the HTML element. Position/size/center this element as desired.

**To get your SVG content centered within the SVG viewport**

1. Set the `viewBox` on your SVG to be centered around the center of your content.
   *For example, if your content is a circle of radius 30 centered at `175,300` then set `viewBox="145 270 60 60"`.*
2. Omit the `preserveAspectRatio` attribute on the SVG element, or ensure that it uses `xMidYMid` so that the center of the viewbox is always centered in the SVG viewport.

**To pan and drag your SVG content**

Adjust the `viewBox` accordingly, or else transform elements.

Comment: Thanks Phrogz but (a) SVNPan doesn't seem to like SVG in HTML (b) I need to be able scale my graphic in absolute pixel multiples i.e. x1, x2, x3, etc. so the `viewBox` would need to be set to the containing element's dimensions which arent't known and (b) yes - can do this with SVGPan which uses transforms.